# WhenAll for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to write a version of `Task.WhenAll` for .NET 3.5 using the "Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5". This is what I came up with. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    public static Task WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        var remainingTasks = tasks.ToList();
        int count = remainingTasks.Count();
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (var task in remainingTasks)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)
                {
                    foreach (var task1 in remainingTasks)
                    {
                        if (task1.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            exceptions.Add(task1.Exception);
                        }
                    }

                    if (exceptions.Any())
                    {
                        tcs.SetException(new AggregateException(exceptions));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure but shouldn't the SetException code be outside the foreach loop?

Comment: Well your code almost looks like the decompiled one from Microsoft, did you have a look at it? =)

Comment: I did indeed :) Was hoping it would be simpler, hence this attempt.

Comment: Trying to outsmart library code is generally a losing game.  Most of the time when you think you've found a simpler solution, what you've really done is removed the ability to handle one or more edge case failure.  Unless you understand what the removed code is doing and are certain the case will never occur you're setting a time bomb in your code that will eventually go off.  Generally at the worst possible moment.

Comment: The library code wasn't available for .net 3.5. I had a look at the 4.0 version and emulated that. My version is of course inferior but hopefully returns the same result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int count = remainingTasks.Count();
```

Since `remainingTasks` is a `List`, you can use the `Count` property here.

---

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
```

This variable should be declared where it's used: in the `if Interlocked.Decrement` block.

---

```
if (task1.IsFaulted)
```

This means you're treating canceled tasks the same as successfully completed ones. Instead, you can check whether `Exception` is `null`.

You could also rewrite the inner `foreach` using LINQ:

```
var exceptions = remainingTasks
    .Select(task => task.Exception)
    .Where(e => e != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Right. That makes it less confusing :)

Comment: IsFaulted seems to indicate strictly that the task completed due to an exception (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 11):

I like how you've written this code. Just a couple of nitpicks:

#### Consistency with `var`

> ```
>     var remainingTasks = tasks.ToList();
>     int count = remainingTasks.Count();
>     var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
> ```

Why not use `var` to declare `count`? Seems pretty obvious to me that `remainingTasks.Count()` would be an `int`, and it's the only explicitly typed variable in your method.

#### Naming

I don't like `task1`; you should prefer a meaninfgul name here, such as `remainingTask`. Also I'm not sure about `tcs`, I might have called it `completionSource`.

Comment: And `SetException()` is called only once, outside the (inner) `foreach` loop. Was the question edited in the grace period?

Comment: @svick it's called inside the loop, every time a new exception is added to `exceptions`. Unless my reading is wrong. Updated answer with the `SetException` call outside the loop body.

Comment: Your update won't work correctly: `exceptions` is filled only after the last `Task` completes, but the outer `foreach` completes long before that.

Comment: Ugh, true. Is there not a way to move it out of the loop though?

Comment: It will be executed only once (after the last `Task` completes) in the original code; that's what the `if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)` does.

Comment: "Why not use var to declare count?" Because `var` and `int` are the same length, so you'd be hiding the type from the programmer for no benefit. One of the main purposes of `var` is to prevent excessively verbose code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of the fail-fast methodology, so I'd flip around the conditional to:

```
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) > 0)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: 1. The ["real" `WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384) is not an extension method, so this just mirrors that (and not making it an extension method makes sense to me). 2. I don't see how does using generics like that make it more flexible. [A generic overload for `Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766) is useful, but that's not what you're proposing.

Comment: @svick you're right. Removed the crap.